# N Queens problem solution from Cracking the Coding Interview. What would be the Time Complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, n-queens

I managed to understand the solution for the N-Queens problem but I have a slight confusion regarding the time complexity of the solution. I think that overall complexity would be `O(n!*(n^2))`. I know it is wrong. Please help.

```
void placeQueens(int row, vector<int> &columns,int n, vector<vector<int>>&ans)
{      
   if(row==n)
   {
       ans.push_back(columns);
       return;
   }

   for(int col=0;col<n;col++)
   { 
       //O(n) time, the checking take O(n) time
       if(isSafe(row,col,columns))
       { 
           columns[row]=col;
           placeQueens(row+1,columns,n,ans);
       }
   }        
}


bool isSafe(int r1,int c1, vector<int>&columns)
{  
   //check if r1,c1 is safe to place a queen or not
   for(int row=0; row<r1 ; row++)
   {            
       if(columns[row] == c1)
       { 
           //same column 
           return false;
       }
       if(abs(columns[row]-c1) == abs(row-r1))
       { 
           //same diagonal
           return false;
       }   
   }

   return true;
}
```

Now the confusion is that each call of the `placeQueens` function takes `O(n^2)` according to me. Since there is a `for loop` running `n` times and in each iteration of this loop we do `O(n)` work (because the `isSafe` function also takes `O(n)` time. So overall complexity becomes `O(n!*(n^2))`.

I know this is wrong. Please help me understand where am I making a mistake.

Comment: When using Big O, terms other than the largest tend to be dropped.

Comment: Yes but we drop higher order terms when they are additive. Like `O(n!+(n^2))` would become `O(n!)`. But here we have `O(n!*(n^2))`. Please help me understand if there is something else also to be considered.

Comment: `When using Big O, terms other than the largest tend to be dropped`. That's perfectly true. Only, here, there are only factors so we don't drop anything.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer earlier. It does not reduce to `O(n^2 * n!)`. *It has a recurrence relation of the form `T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(n^2)`* which **does not** reduce to `O(n^2 * n!)`. Here is a link for more clarification: codesdope.com/course/algorithms-backtracking

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it does O(n<sup>2</sup>) work for each call to `placeQueens`, but because it only makes recursive calls for *safe* squares that don't conflict with any previous ones, far fewer than n! calls are made.

The top level call will try every square in the top row and make **n** recursive calls, but if n is very large, then almost all choices for the first square will exclude **3** choices for the next row, not **1**.  Similarly, after almost all choices for the 2nd row, **6** squares will be excluded in the 3rd.

If C(n) is the number of calls made for an nxn board, then C(n) will be not too far from n(n-3)(n-6)...

For sure we have C(n) < n(n-2)(n-4)(n-6)...(n-sqrt(n))O((n-sqrt(n))!), and so we know that n!/C(n) grows *faster than any polynomial*.

Therefore, as long as each call to `placeQueens` does a polynomial amount of work, then the complexity is *certainly* in O(n!).